# Re-order records in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been trying to order records in the controller but dont work, I've been trying this:

```
@reldaycli = Reldayc.ruta(params[:id]).dia_con_clientes(params[:id2]).ordered_by_title
```

and the scope to order:

```
scope :ordered_by_title, -> { reorder(Lunes: :asc) }

  scope :dia_con_clientes, -> (id_param22) {where("Lunes > ?", '0')}

  scope :ruta, -> (id_param) { where(RutaId: id_param) }
```

but don't work

Comment: Would you please post the content of the other scopes/methods referenced in this line (`ruta` and `dia_con_clientes`) as well as the column names for the table you are trying to order?

Comment: @rebagliatte updated :) the column name I trying to order is Lunes

Comment: Thanks. You are probably having an issue with rails naming conventions, as it expects column names to be in snake_case. Also is the 'Lunes' column a boolean?

Comment: @rebagliatte the column 'Lunes' is int

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: No error, the scope It's not ordering :(

Comment: Have you tried `order()` instead of `reorder()`?

Comment: Is your project open source? If so can you post its repository URL so we can take a look?